# convert a embedded json string into pandas dataframe

Tags: python, json, pandas

I have following data:

```
json_str = "[{“key1”: “value1”, “key2”= “value2”, 
“key3”: “{“key_a”: “value_a1”, “key_b”: “value_b1”, “key_c”: “value_c1”}”,“key4”: 4},
{“key1”: “value5”, “key2”= “value6”, 
“key3”: “{“key_a”: “value_a2”, “key_b”: “value_b2”, “key_c”: “value_c2”}”,“key4”: 8}]"
```

which i want  to convert into pandas DataFrame. 
i have tried this :

```
#code1
data = pd.read_json(json_str)
print(data)

#code2
data = pd.read_json(json_str, typ ='series')
print(data)

#code3
data = pd.DataFrame.from_dict([json_str], orient='columns', dtype= None)
print(data)

#same output
ValueError: Unexpected character found when decoding object value
```

Again:

```
data = json.loads(json_str)
print(data)
enter code here
error : json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting ',' delimiter
```

I couldnot use .replace() as i need to have a column name "key3" which contains JSON values 
for eg: {“key_a”: “value_a1”, “key_b”: “value_b1”, “key_c”: “value_c1”}

Comment: your data is not uniform. You have `key:` like this and also `key=`

Comment: Thanks for pointing it out. now, it's edited.

Comment: you have still hot `“key2”= “value2”`

Comment: The magic quotes are also likely not so good.

Comment: No, this is uniform. I think. 
key1.....key4 are all same, but values are deifferent

Comment: yes, exactly. but can't deal with it @StephenRauch

Comment: Suggest you figure out how to make your string loadable with `json.loads()`

Comment: You might consider `.replace()`

Comment: i have updated the question @StephenRauch

Comment: Use the `.replace()` to fix your json quotes....  Then when it parses, pandas will likely work.  If not, then let us know.

Comment: So didn't the answer help???

Answer (score 0):

There is a need for cleaning of data, here's one way of doing it

```
from functools import reduce
import ast

di = {'“':"'", '”':"'", "'{":'{', "}'":"}", "=":':' }

new = reduce(lambda x, y: x.replace(y, di[y]), di, json)

df = pd.io.json.json_normalize(ast.literal_eval(new))

print(df)

     key1    key2 key3.key_a key3.key_b key3.key_c  key4
0  value1  value2   value_a1   value_b1   value_c1     4
1  value5  value6   value_a2   value_b2   value_c2     8
```